# GXT - RowEditor marks CheckColumnConfig as modified

Tags: gridview, checkbox, grid, gxt

I'm using a CheckColumnConfig in conjunction with a RowEditor.  The CheckColumnConfig is used to indicate a row in the Grid which the user wants to "Select" maybe to delete the row or indicate to the application which row the user is working on.  If the user clicks any other cell in the row the RowEditor is invoked and the user carries on as usual.

If the user updates any cell, the RowEditor also "flags" the CheckColumnConfig checkbox as modified (with the little red triangle in the upper-left corner).  I have a work-around in my code that ignores the checkbox but it's a pain (and ugly).  Any way to stop the RowEditor from marking the CheckColumnConfig as modified?

Comment: If you want to add an image into your question, just past the link, someone will update your question to embed the image.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you probably have already solved your issue by the way you should use a *GridView* and set the *setShowDirtyCells* property to *false*.
Then add the *view* to your grid with *grid.setView(view)*